# Tkinter canvas - time and hiding image

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, raspberry-pi

I am writing a python code using Tkinter/canvas.

```
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1800, height=900, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='image2.png')
root.photo = photo
canvas.create_image(1000,500,image=photo)
```

this is my background which I work with, works perfectly fine, but then I have a little problem with some parts. I need to put another image there in 1 part of the loop/code/if and in another part I need to "hide" it so I can show it and hide whenever I want. This is how i create it, but I can't solve the hiding part.

```
shine = tk.PhotoImage(file='svetlo.png')
smaller_image = shine.subsample(6, 6) 
Svetlo = canvas.create_image(260, 830, image=smaller_image)
```

and my second problem is how I show date and time. RN I am using this

```
time1 = canvas.create_text(1000,500,text = strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

But it show just one time and doesnt change (obviously) and I dont know, how to make it work. I tried to find a solution, but only thing I found was only label and it doesn't work with my canvas, I need that time at the canvas. Thank you

Comment: You can use `canvas.itemconfig(Svetlo, state='hidden')` to hide the small image and `canvas.itemconfig(Svetlo, state='normal')` to show it.  And you need to use `after()` to update the time periodically.

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much!